# How to pass data from TableViewCell to a ViewController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uitableview

Okay i read many articles about it but i want to have a suggestion for this . So my `tableViewCell` looks like this :

[image]

if a user tap on the name `Akshay Kheveria` it will perform segue to a view controller and show the profile of `Akshay Kheveria` . So what i'm thinking is just pass the objectId of the user and load the required data from parse in another viewController..So:

1. How can i do that?
2. Is this the right way of doing this or there's something else to know about??

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have the user data of only object Id of user while transitioning?

Comment: Good answers here about how to assign a property on the destination vc, but they both suggest assigning to an id property.  If the destination vc needs a PFObject (probably) and you have one (probably) then assign the PFObject.

Answer (score 3):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "ToProfile"
  {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ProfileViewController{
        destinationVC.profileId = yourObjectId
    }
  }
}
```

Try  this..

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the `(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method.
Start by creating a public property (header file) in your ViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *profileId;
```

Save the cell selected by user when he touched the pseudo, like this for example :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToProfile" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Then

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
    SomeObject* tableViewItem = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ToProfile"]) {
        ProfileViewController *profile = [segue destinationViewController];

        profile.profileId = tableViewItem.profileId;
    }
}
```

So now you can access the profileId property from your ViewController.

Comment: When a segue is triggered via cell selection, the `sender` parameter is the selected cell itself. So there is no need to store a property for the selected cell, and you can use `[self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]` to retrieve the index in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Comment: Oh nice ! I didn't know. Thank you

Comment: can you explain this in Swift?

Comment: No sorry, I don't know Swift, but I'm sure the function are the same.